# Data Transfer from Oracle to Neo4J

Tags: oracle, neo4j

I'm working with Neo4j for a family tree, It works fine but I just use the fake data, the real data is being stored in the Oracle database and I want to transfer data from Oracle to Neo4j. For each row in the Person table, there is a node in Neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j and [APOC procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) support ingesting data via a JDBC driver. Check out more in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-integration/load-jdbc/). If you have lots of data you want to wrap the procedure in `apoc.periodic.iterate` for batching purpose like:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/northwind?user=root","company")',
  'CREATE (p:Person) SET p += value',
  { batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
RETURN batches, total
```